# Unable to view list library in content Query web part

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I have a new CQWP and when l export the WP and insert it into the page layout when l create a new page it adds the CQWP but the it doesn't show the list l have selected in the Query under "show items from the following list" I have to do this manually every time do you know which property name l have to update for it to include the library every time l create a new page

Comment: Are you sure you are tried to add the CQWP in a site page within the same web application?

Comment: Yes I have tested on same site collection

Comment: Try to configure your CQWP and export it again then add it on your page,

Answer (score 0):

**By default,** the `Content Query Web Part Export Operation` preserves the `list/library Name`

```
<property name="ListName" type="string">Qassas List</property>
```

It also preserves `WebUrl`

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~sitecollection/Qassas/test</property>
```

**So**

- Try to export the CQWP again then add it on your page, it should be working properly.
- Also, Make sure that you already added the exported CQWP in a site page within the same web application!

Comment: Tried that but when l re-add it back in l get the following message :    [There is a problem with the query that this Web Part is issuing. Check the configuration of this Web Part and try again.] but if l edit the CQWP it resolved automatically same with adding it in the display template l have to edit it for the entries to appear

Comment: what's your current SharePoint version?

Comment: 2013 version, so if my url is (http://TESTING/Lists/TEST%20Board/AllItems.aspx) so would l use <property name="WebUrl" type="string">~sitecollection/TESTBoard</property> or would l need to include the site collection name ?